# IAM Permissions for a CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to set up my deployment pipelines so that they adhere to the principle of least privilege when they deploy assets to AWS. That means I don't want to give the deployment policy admin access or "*:*" privileges.

The problem is that every time I create a new pipeline I have to go through a trial and error process:

- Deploy
- Get a failure due to missing IAM permissions
- Update IAM Policy to add the missing permission
- Repeat

I've searched for resources to help with this, but the general approach seems to be to *overprovision* the IAM policy, which I think is a really bad approach.

Are there any tools which you can use which will analyse a CloudFormation template and generate a JSON document of the required deployment policy? (Or for Serverless Framework or CDK?)

Answer (score 6):

Great question, unfortunately, the answer is slightly tricky.

You're running up against a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem with all Infrastructure As Code providers (Serverless, CDK, CloudFormation, Terraform, etc).

Keep in mind that the IAM user which *deploys* your application is *not* the same as the IAM role that your application (Lambda) *runs* under.

This means that if you wanted to strictly limit the permissions of your deploy user so that it could only deploy specific resources, that's fine - however as you noted, you'll need to expand those permissions every time you want to deploy new resources. Notably, if you automate this process such that the role permissions are expanded every time you add new infrastructure - you've effectively granted your deploy user administrative access.

This is why most people use an over-provisioned deploy user in order to deploy their applications. It's not considered a bad approach for two reasons:

1. Your application does not use this role when executing, so if you had some major vulnerability in your lambda that allowed for remote code execution, the attacker couldn't compromise your entire AWS account
2. You're relying on your IAC provider to ensure that you do not create unneeded infrastructure. (IE: you and your IAC provider have the same level of access)

As long as the Lambda Execution role has a strict IAM policy, using an overprovisioned deployment user is fine.

Comment: Thanks @aaron-stuyvenberg. I think you make a good point about managing risk. However, I do have concerns about having relatively "open" deployment roles. It is easy for someone with access to the code repository to have the pipeline provision additional resources, such as escalated permissions. In an extreme case, they may provision an administrator policy, for example.

Comment: Yeah absolutely. Although most organizations I've worked with generally allow their deployment roles a wide latitude, you can always include specific denies for these types of things.

There many cases for needing your IAC provider to create a new role as part of a deployment (especially if you use something like terraform to manage your employees user accounts). In that case, IAM actually doesn't allow you to block specific parts of the policy IIRC. (So allowing a user to createRole effectively gives them administrator access).

In that case, I'd limit access to the code pipeline itself.

Comment: To restrict a deploy role from creating a new role with admin access, you can attach a permissions boundary: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html . The boundary can allow the `iam:CreateRole` action with the `iam:PermissionsBoundary`  condition key so that any role the deploy role creates must have the boundary attached as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_identityandaccessmanagement.html#identityandaccessmanagement-iam_PermissionsBoundary